# Convert ascii string to base64 without the "b" and quotation marks

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64

I wanted to convert an ascii string (well just text  to be precise) towards base64.
So I know how to do that, I just use the following code:

```
import base64
string = base64.b64encode(bytes("string", 'utf-8'))
print (string)
```

Which gives me

```
b'c3RyaW5n'
```

However the problem is, I'd like it to just print

```
c3RyaW5n
```

Is it possible to print the string without the "b" and the '' quotation marks?
Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `b` prefix denotes that it is a **binary string**. A binary string is *not* a string: it is a sequence of bytes (values in the 0 to 255 range). It is simply typesetted as a string to make it more compact.

In case of base64 however, all characters are valid ASCII characters, you can thus simply decode it like:

```
print(string.decode('ascii'))
```

So here we will decode each byte to its ASCII equivalent. Since base64 guarantees that every byte it produces is in the ASCII range `'A'` to `'/'`) we will always produce a valid string. Mind however that this is *not* guaranteed with an arbitrary binary string.

Answer (score 8):

A simple `.decode("utf-8")` would do

```
import base64
string = base64.b64encode(bytes("string", 'utf-8'))
print (string.decode("utf-8"))
```